# Syntax Error at sep=

Tags: python

I am receiving a syntax error for the = sign following sep in this function, which is part of a markov process meant to simulate natural language.

Here is the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
***-MacBook-Air:proj3 ***$ python proj3.py
  File "proj3.py", line 94
    print(' ',sep="",end='')
```

Here is the relevant portion of the function, it is the final sep that is giving me the problem:

```
def generate(self):
    #if '' in self.rules:
    #    del self.rules['']
    string_length = randint(50,100)
    c = 0
    n = '.'
    while c < string_length:
        n = self.getitem(n)   
        if c == string_length-1:
            print('.')
            break 
        if n == '.' or n == ',':
            pass
        else:
            print(' ',sep='',end='')
        print(n, sep='',end='')
        if n == '.' and c >= string_length-20:
            c = string_length 
        c = c + 1
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  The `sep=` argument is only valid in Python 3.

Comment: `python proj3.py`, you should use Python 3 for this to work.